# SaaS, SOA and Web Services

Tags: web-services, soa, saas

This question may be foolish, but I am really confused.

I want to implement a Software as a Service (SaaS), and I thought that I can use Visual Studio and WCF to do it. But I've read that WCF and Web Services are a SOA implementation and not a SaaS.

Can I use WCF to implement a SaaS? What's the relation between SaaS, SOA and Web Services?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**[SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) is just a method of software delivery.** Think of it this way: You are a software provider and you need to provide your clients with software applications that they want to use. But you don't sell them a DVD and say: *"Here! Go install this on your servers and use it"*. You instead host the application on your own servers and - for a subscription fee - provide users access to it over the web. It's externalization of applications (e.g. email, human resources application, accounting and taxes etc).

**When we talk SaaS, we talk fully functional standalone applications** that offer some business service.

[SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) is something similar but at a lower level. It doesn't provide business service but instead provides small isolated processes as a service.

**SOA is an architecture style to building software.** The idea is that you build your application by putting together (or interacting with) a set of stateless, reusable, 
decoupled network services (e.g. [web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)).

**I think what confuses people is the term "service". Both SaaS and SOA provide "services".** But it's the target that's different: SOA offers services to other applications as opposed to SaaS that offers services to users.

**You can off course use SOA to build your SaaS application.** It's not mandatory but its often preferable. With SaaS you provide services to more clients and having it built on top of a SOA architecture makes the application easier to scale than a more monolithic "do it all" application.

[TL;DR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk%3aTLDR): I'll paraphrase something I've read on a [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2007/04/08/saas-and-soa.aspx):

> Deciding to deliver tax capabilities over the web, is SaaS.
>   Enabling the tax application to integrate with IRS for e-filing and internal return verification, is SOA.

Comment: "*SOA offers services to other applications as opposed to SaaS that offers services to users.*" Great point.